# Setup wizard on samsung phone: run or make it run

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung

How can i make a samsung phone, go through setup wizard again so the end user may personalize the phone?

I tried the factory reset but it wipes all data and applications installed, my interest is to keep applications and only wipe existing user data.

Is there any way to run it through ADB?... (this way i can only turn the phone off and let the end user handle the rest)

Comment: See e.g.: [Trigger Setup Wizard at next boot using command-line](/q/137324/16575)

Answer (score 0):

You can't factory reset a phone and keep applications.  This is by design.

> my interest is to keep applications and only wipe existing user data

Apps are tied to a **user**, not a device.

Actually, the reason is because of Google's Terms of Service:

https://play.google.com/intl/en-us_us/about/play-terms.html

When you download an application from Google Play, you are agreeing to the ToS.  Setting up a new user with pre-installed applications breaks the agreement between Google and the end-user, since agreement happens at *install* time.

This is also why multi-account devices also do not share applications - each user is required to "agree" to fair use of each app.

Additionally, using the [App Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) service, developers can block use of apps that haven't been licensed to the current user properly.

Finally, Google has been [urging app developers](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/user-data/) to include EULA within their apps thus corroborating the above.

All that being said, if you had root permissions, you could make any apps system level apps and theoretically circumvent this issue - but I wouldn't recommend nor endorse it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a few months on my tablet, and here is the general way I did it.

I used the app 3CTools and found the system app on my tablet that contained the Activity to for the setup wizard.

I believe it was Settings.apk but not sure.

Then I used Terminal emulator to start activity.
pm start com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SetupWizzardActivity

Or something very close to that.
Hope this helped

TwilightTime